# PHP http_build_query() generate incorrect url for array get parameter

Tags: php, arrays, url, get

I probably discovered a bug of a PHP function http_build_query().

I am developing a search engine with dynamic form and some of these parameters are array.

I simply get the query url from the current $_GET with http_build_query().
But all of these array parameters are **automatically changed from "arrayName%5B%5D" to "arrayName%5B0%5D"** in the new query generated.

```
$queryStr = http_build_query($_GET);
```

> **original url**
>
> &arrayName%5B%5D=
>
> **new query string got from http_build_query():**
>
> &arrayName%5B**0**%5D=

**What is the reason for this? How to fix this?**

Comment: Please provide a replication case (e.g. the value of $_GET that you see the problem with). Seems unlikely to be a bug.

Comment: If I'm reading this right though, it's perfectly reasonable. Your sub-array can't have a value with no index, so it's put the index in as I would expect it to.

Comment: I hv never manipulated the content of $_GET before applying the function. so how come index 0 is automatically added?

Comment: Sorry, your comment doesn't make any sense.

Comment: coz i didn't finished it but pressed save by mistake edited the comment

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. I'm not sure how manipulating $_GET comes into this. Array values _have_ to have indicies. If one isn't specified, then the lowest available number is used, starting from zero. This is how array work in PHP.

Comment: it is supposed to work fine when i haven't even touched anything of $_GET. right? And isn't setting a get parameter to sth like array[] a common practice?

Comment: Try `var_dump($_GET);` and see what it gives you. You'll see that an index has been auto-generated (as it should) for `arrayName` items. When you use `http_build_query` the index gets put in too since that's the only thing that makes sense. I'm not sure how else to explain this...

Comment: ya, tried. The get array I got of coz has all the elements assigned  with indexes automatically after the form is submitted. If I never touched this, the array is supposed to be intact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug to http_build_query() function.

When you pass the get parameter via URL like: "arrayName[]="

```
print_R($_GET);
```

will return

```
Array
(
    [arrayName] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)
```

and [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.http-build-query.php) generates the url encoded string from array, the result is:

```
&arrayName%5B0%5D=
```

and decoded this looks like:

```
arrayName[0]=
```

Now you can see where the 0 came from :)

There is no need to fix this, you can change your code to pass keys for the arrayName or still use it as is.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we are using multiple checkboxes with ASC/DESC orders.
For that previously provided solution not working.

$queryStr = http_build_query($_GET);

$queryStr = urldecode($queryStr);

$queryStr = preg_replace('/[[0-9]+]/', '[]', $queryStr);

**This solution works fine for me.**

Forex. [https://example.com?s=LorumText&post_type[]=blog](https://example.com?s=LorumText&post_type%5B%5D=blog)

// Now your string won't be converted into hashcode(%5B0%5D=), It remains with []

Current Result: https://example.com?s=LorumText&post_type %5B0%5D=blog

**Updated Result: [https://example.com?s=LorumText&post_type[]=blog](https://example.com?s=LorumText&post_type%5B%5D=blog)**

Comment: Hacking at a strictly formatted string with regex seems extremely unwise to me because it runs the risk of damaging values while mutating the key syntax.  I do not recommend using this answer's advice for data integrity/stability reasons.  Furthermore, `http_build_query()` is not broken and does not need to be fixed.